# Finding a number in a field via php

Tags: php

I want to get true when it finds "0"
I couldn't get that with these codes:

```
 if (strstr($rSelect['date'],"0") !=FALSE){...}

 if (strpos($rSelect['date'],'0') !=FALSE )
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to run some code if there is a "0" in $rSelect['date']. $rSelect['date']: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
if (strrchr($rSelect['date'],"0") !== false) {
    echo "No found";
} else {
    echo "Match Found";
}
```

Comment: Yah strrchr....sorry I directly copied from question but forgot to change it...

Answer (score 0):

try strpos() for more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$mystring = $rSelect['date'];
    $findme   = '0';
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
    if ($pos === false) {
        echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
    } else {
        echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
        echo " and exists at position $pos";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only **[`strrchr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)** to check whether 0 is present inside that string or not.

```
if(strrchr('1234', "0") != false) {
    echo 'present';
} else {
    echo 'not present';
}
```

### *Codepad demo*

Comment: thanks, what is difference between !==False and !=false?

Comment: @PooriaFarhad `!==` checks for non-similarity as well as data type of both, and `!=` checks for non-similarity.

Comment: @PooriaFarhad Why are you not accepting answer, after you get correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `$rSelect['date']` is a [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), your second form is correct. Use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for this.

```
if (strpos($rSelect['date'], '0') !== false) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

If `$rSelect['date']` is an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array('0', $rSelect['done'])) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```